# C# Timer elapsed one instance at a time

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I am creating windows service. I want to run the service every 30 seconds.

So I have used timer on windows service start using the following code.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 30000;
            timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer1_tick);
            timer1.Start();
        }
```

In timer1_tick function, I am performing some actions like updating user details, uploading and downloading files.

But here I am not sure that the above action will finish within 30 seconds.
So I want to run one at a time.

Here **timer1_tick function** called every exact 30 seconds. This should be happen only if the **timer1_tick function** finishes every task.

How to do that?

Comment: In your timer's tick event stop the timer, do your logic and finally start the timer again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should stop the timer and wait for the uploading and downloading of files to finish using `Timer.Stop();` and `Timer.Start()`:

```
void timer1_tick(...){
    timer1.Stop();
    //Do your download, upload, etc.
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No problem. Good luck! :)

Comment: @JeevaJsb I would wrap tick action in try..catch..finally and restart timer in finally block. If something goes wrong with logic in timer's event you don't want your windows service to fall over and risk timer not running next time.

Comment: @JeevaJsb  that' a great suggestion. I always use try...catch with my methods.

Comment: Yes I did the same.. Thanks @Hakunamatata for the precaution

Comment: instead of immediately stopping the timer, you can setup the timer to run once like this :  timer1.AutoReset=false.  Then you just Start() it again when your routine has finished. It has the same result but looks a bit cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

As per your requirement use Asynchronous Programming. It might be help you. Thank You

```
timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(await timer1_tick);

async Task<void> timer1_tick()
{
//Do your download, upload, etc.
}
```

Comment: this will not prevent that multiple instances are running simultaneously (they are just in non-blocking separate threads)