# Thread creation in method which is being called for several times using timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I have a timer using which i am calling a method - {OnElapsedTime} And this should responsible for database access and updation for every interval of time.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        ServiceLogFile("Service is started at " + DateTime.Now);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tracktime"]); //number in miliseconds  
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ServiceLogFile("Error in {OnStart} :" + ex.ToString());
    }

}
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ServiceLogFile("Check for Database values - " + DateTime.Now);
        th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Autocancellation));
        int ThreadID = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        ServiceLogFile("Thread ID = " + ThreadID);
        th.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ServiceLogFile("Error in {OnElapsedTime} :" + ex.ToString());
    }
}

public void Autocancellation()
{
    try
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            //connection to database 
             //select Query and update 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message());
    }
}
```

If we can see the above code - I am creating a new thread for every OnElapsedTime call.

Please help me with creating a single thread outside of this method or anywhere and using the same instance inside {OnElapsedTime} whenever this method is being called (In my case - 5 seconds)

Comment: A few questions: 1. Do you need to run all the Autocancellation "jobs" in the order they appear (once per 5 seconds) or do you want to skip them when previous one is not yet completed? 2. Do you have to use threads for some reasons or is an alternative approach acceptable?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Autocancellation method updates the database values for every 5 seconds. And then it returns back to {OnElapsedTime} irrespective of how much data left to update. And again Autocancellation  would be called to update the remaining.

Comment: My goal is to Call the database method for every 5 seconds and try to check if there is a new data and if so, update some columns based on the conditions. If the database has a big set of rows (data) at the moment - My update thread would be shared among the available system thread and that leads to Update error - So i came up with calling the Database method using Thread and locking it .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

1. that we properly implement [cooperative cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads) (otherwise there are no reliable ways to stop the currently running job)
2. And we are not forced to use threads - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl
3. And we are not required to run exactly once per 5 seconds (to accommodate the cooperative cancellation from bullet 1) - [C# Timer elapsed one instance at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221178/c-sharp-timer-elapsed-one-instance-at-a-time)

the simplest (or rather the simplest without any additional [libraries](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/)) way would be to use Task, TaskCancellationSource and a timer with `AutoReset = false`

```
public class Service
{
    private Task _job;
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;

    public Service()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        {
            _timer.AutoReset = false;
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds;    
            _timer.Elapsed += OnElapsedTime;
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting service");
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnElapsedTime");
        if (_job != null)
        {
            CancelAndWaitForPreviousJob();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Starting new job");
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _job = Task.Run(
            () => ExecuteJob(_cancellationTokenSource.Token), 
            _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void CancelAndWaitForPreviousJob()
    {               
         _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();   
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for job to complete");
            _job.Wait(
                millisecondsTimeout: 5000); // Add additional timeout handling?  
        }                
        catch (OperationCanceledException canceledExc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Cancelled the execution: {canceledExc}");
        }     
        catch (Exception exc) 
        {                    
            Console.WriteLine($"Some unexpected exception occurred - ignoring: {exc}");
        }
    }

    private void ExecuteJob(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ExecuteJob start");
        try
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Job loop Iteration {i}");
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cancellation requested - ending ExecuteJob");
                    return;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ExecuteJob end");
        }
    }
}
```

While it is a working solution you may be interested in [Quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) - it has only a moderate learning curve and it is designed exactly for such scenarios.

P.S.: Also it seems that your application is a service based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase?view=netframework-4.8. In such a case you may be interested in [topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) - it greatly simplifies a lot of things related to services.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm new to Threading and timing concept of programming. I will read more on the documents you have shared and try to deploy the same ideas and get back to you on the same.